# How to keep website width fixed (irrespective of screen size)

Tags: html, css

I am designing a website. I want my website to be 980px width. I can easily do it on my laptop by setting the `right` and `left` fields of CSS Box as 15%. But my concern is that, when my website is opened on another PC with no widescreen, that 15% will create a distortion. I want to keep my website at 980px whatever be the screen size may be. Please help!

As you can see in the image attached. The boxes are 15% distance from sides. If screen will be shorter for a pc, then these boxes will overlap.[image: Screen shot of my website]

Comment: Um define the width to be 980px... ? I'm missing something where do you get percentages in there?  Or are you asking about margin %?

Comment: while creating a box using CSS, I fixed that left box is 15% away from left border of browser and right box is 15% away from right border of the browser. I am talking about left and right margin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than trying to explicitly set the left and right margins, just have it auto center.

```
<div style="width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 80%;">Left Column</div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 20%;">Right Column</div>
</div>
```

The key is the `auto` margin for left and right. This will horizontally align that 980px div in the center and keeping the width no matter what.

Comment: If you see the picture, there are two boxes side by side. Looking at only a single box (any of them), you will find that neither of them is in center. But if see both boxes are a single box, then it is in center. This is my concern. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Yes, add a containing `div` that houses the left and right div. I will update my answer with more code.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following style rules to create fixed-width cross-browser compatible layouts:

```css
body { min-width: 980px; text-align: center; }
#wrapper { width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; }
```

Put a div with ID "wrapper" inside your body tag, and the wrapper will always be at the center of the screen, and will always by 980px;

Answer (score 0):

set the width on body tag and set CSS style align to center

Comment: @iSumitG, nothing is created by CSS, its HTML under the hood, CSS just styles it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a container div for the portion of the page that you want to be 980px, and set it to `width: 980px; margin: 0 auto` so that it will be centered and 980px.